# Dynamic policy and signature creation for browser uploads to Amazon S3

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I would like to select a file in an HTML form and upload it directly to Amazon S3. I understand the principles of browser-based uploads to S3 using POST, but how can I create a policy and signature for the form if I haven't yet chosen a file to upload? Should I use AJAX to send the filename to my server and return an appropriate policy and signature based on the file extension?

Comment: Sorry. Realised that I can overcome this with `["starts-with", "$Content-Type", ""]` or `["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "audio/"]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax, Flash or any other method to upload the file to your server and then transfer it to the Amazon S3.

Comment: But wouldn't it be more efficient to upload it directly to S3?